# Hyper-prparameter tuning and classification algorithm comparation

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, comparison, hyperparameters

I have a doubt about classification algorithm comparation.

I am doing a project regarding hyperparameter tuning and classification model comparation for a dataset.
The Goal is to find out the best fitted model with the best hyperparameters for my dataset.

For example: I have 2 classification models (SVM and Random Forest), my dataset has 1000 rows and 10 columns (9 columns are features) and 1 last column is lable.

First of all, I splitted dataset into 2 portions (80-10) for training (800 rows) and tesing (200rows) correspondingly. After that, I use Grid Search with CV = 10 to tune hyperparameter on training set with these 2 models (SVM and Random Forest). When hyperparameters are identified for each model, I use these hyperparameters of these 2 models to test Accuracy_score on training and testing set again in order to find out which model is the best one for my data (conditions: Accuracy_score on training set < Accuracy_score on testing set (not overfiting) and which Accuracy_score on testing set of model is higher, that model is the best model).

However, SVM shows the accuracy_score of training set is 100 and the accuracy_score of testing set is 83.56, this means SVM with tuning hyperparameters is overfitting. On the other hand, Random Forest shows the accuracy_score of training set is 72.36 and the accuracy_score of testing set is 81.23. It is clear that the accuracy_score of testing set of SVM is higher than the accuracy_score of testing set of Random Forest, but SVM is overfitting.

I have some question as below:

_ Is my method correst when I implement comparation of accuracy_score for training and testing set as above instead of using Cross-Validation? (if use Cross-Validation, how to do it?

_ It is clear that SVM above is overfitting but its accuracy_score of testing set is higher than accuracy_score of testing set of Random Forest, could I conclude that SVM is a best model in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to use the tuned hyperparameters again on your training set. You should report the mean CV score from your 10 CV runs. Another thing to note is that your CV samples must be the same for both models if you want to effectively compare them. Consider using the same random number seed generator if you haven't done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good that you've done quite an analysis on your part to investigate the best model. However, I would suggest you elaborate on your investigation a bit. As you're searching for the best model for your data, **"Accuracy" alone is not a good evaluation metric** for your models. You should also evaluate your model on **"Precision Score", "Recall Score", "ROC", "Sensitivity", "Specificity"** etc. Find out if your data has imbalance (If they do, there're techniques to work 'em around). After evaluating all those metrics you may come up with a decision.

For the training-testing part, you're quite on the right track, with only one issue (which is quite severe), the time you're testing your model on the test set, **you're injecting a sort of bias**. So I would say make 3 partitions of your data, and use cross-validation (sklearn has got what you need for this) on your **"training set"**, after cross-validation, you may use another partition **"validation set"** for testing the generalization power of your model (performance on unseen data), you may change some parameter after that. And after you've come up to a conclusion and tuning everything you needed to, only then use your **"test set"**. **No matter what the results are (on the test set) don't change the model after that**, as those scores represent the true capability of your model.

*you can create 3 partitions of your data in the following way for example-*

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
 
#  Dummy dataset for example purpose
 X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=2, n_features=2, cluster_std=6.0)

# first partition i.e. "train-set" and "test-set"
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.9, random_state=123)

# second partition, we're splitting the "train-set" into 2 sets, thus creating a new partition of "train-set" and "validation-set"
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, train_size=0.9, random_state=123)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, X_val.shape)  # output : ((810, 2), (100, 2), (90, 2))
```

Comment: Can I have one more question? How can I use another partition "validation set" for testing the generalization power of model as you recommend? How to do it in python? Can you give an example in Python? Thank

Comment: couldn't add the code in a comment, so I edited my answer, you can see how you may make 3 partitions. After training and cross-validating your data on the "train-set", you can simply evaluate the predictions of your model on "validation-set", which will give you an idea of how it may generalize to new data. So then, you may make some correction/fine-tuning in your model, then try again predicting the validation-set. That's how you can approach doing it.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question: As you recommendation that "use cross-validation  on my "training set", after cross-validation, I may use another partition "validation set" for testing the generalization power of my model (performance on unseen data), I may change some parameter after that". How can I use "validation set" for testing the generalization power of my model? Thank you!

Comment: You can use the "validation set" just like you were using the "test set" before to check how well your model is performing on unseen data. To be more clear, you can do something like `predictions = model.predict(X_val)` then you might want to use those predictions to calculate various metrics such as precision, recall, etc. Those would give you some idea if your model is performing well, and you may want to tune some parameters after that and repeat the process again until you're satisfied with the performance on "validation set". Hope it gives you some idea now.

Comment: Great, I got the idea, thank you for your such detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting your data into three sets, rather than two:

1. Training
2. Validation
3. Testing

Training is used to train the model, as you have been doing. The validation set is used to evaluate the performance of a model trained with a given set of hyperparameters. The optimal set of hyperparameters is then used to generate predictions on the test set, which wasn't part of either training or hyper parameter selection. You can then compare performance on the test set between your classifiers.

The large decrease in performance on your SVM model on your validation dataset does suggest overfitting, though it is common for a classifier to perform better on the training dataset than an evaluation or test dataset.

Comment: Assume that SVM is overfitting but the accuracy_score on testing set is higher than Random forest (83.56 > 81.23). So, which algorithms should I choose?

Comment: In this case I would prefer the SVM, despite the fact it seems to be over fitting. Evaluation on data that the model hasn't seen during training is the most important thing, that the SVM is overfitting just suggests that performance could potentially be improved further via methods such as normalization, a different set of hyperparameters, etc. You can also use nested cross-validation, where you also subset the data into many test set folds, analogous to how the data is subset into many validation tests during cross-validation. This provides a distribution of performance values.

Comment: What is ratio usually used for Training and Validation?

Comment: It depends on how large your dataset is. For the amount you have, an 80:10:10 or a 70:15:15 would be good enough(train:test:validation)

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, yes your SVM would be overfitting although in most machine-learning cases, the training set's accuracy would not really matter. It is much more important to look at the testing set's accuracy. It is not unusual to have a higher training accuracy than testing accuracy so I suggest to not look to overfitting and only look at the difference in the testing accuracy. With the information provided, yes you could say that the SVM is the best model in your case.

For your first question, you are already doing a type of cross validation and it is an acceptable way to do evaluate the model.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59630/test-accuracy-higher-than-training-how-to-interpret) might be a useful article for you to read

Comment: I only use Grid Search (a type of cross validation) to preceed hyper-parameter tuning. After tuning, I use these tuned hyperparameter to evaluate model by looking for accuracy_score. Is it acceptable?

Comment: it is definitely acceptable if you use the same hyper parameters for both as it should give an unbiased evaluation of the model